# SQL Server : replace distinct values with ints when nested

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Edited for MySQL.

I have a nested tree of data in a table and I need to number them. It's easy to find the distinct values, get the row number and then use that, by I have a nested tree and need to do that for each level.

My table looks like this (I'm showing three levels, but I actually have four or more)

```
col1, col2, col3, some data cols ....
-----------------------------------
'AAA', 'AA', 'A', #####
'AAA', 'AA', 'B', #####
'AAA', 'AA', 'C', #####
'AAA', 'BB', 'D', #####
'AAA', 'BB', 'E', #####
'AAA', 'BB', 'F', #####
'BBB', 'CC', 'G', #####
'BBB', 'CC', 'H', #####
'BBB', 'CC', 'I', #####
'BBB', 'DD', 'J', #####
'BBB', 'DD', 'K', #####
'BBB', 'DD', 'L', #####
```

etc...

There is more data than that, and AAA represents some string, etc

What I need is for each distinct in col1, replace (or put in a new table) the values 1, 2, 3, etc

Then for each distinct in col1, find the distinct in col2 and replace with 1, 2, 3, etc. Repeat for col3.

To get something like this

```
col1, col2, col3, some data cols ....
   1,    1,   1, #####
   1,    1,   2, #####
   1,    1,   3, #####
   1,    2,   1, #####
   1,    2,   2, #####
   1,    2,   3, #####
   2,    1,   1, #####
   2,    1,   2, #####
   2,    1,   3, #####
   2,    2,   1, #####
   2,    2,   2, #####
   2,    2,   3, #####
```

Is this doable via a SQL script?

So the answers provided work perfectly for Microsoft SQL. 
Is there a way to do it in MySQL?
None of the functions seem to be present there.

Comment: it is Rank() , row_number will give unique values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like....

```
select 
  DENSE_RANK() OVER ( order by col1)                                 Col1
 ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 order by col1,col2)           Col2
 ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY col1,col2 order by col1,col2,col3) Col3
From TableName
```

Comment: Perfect! That did exactly what I was looking for. I wasn't aware of the Partition by command.

Comment: This worked wonderfully for ms sql. Now I need to do it in MySQL. None of these functions exist there. Any ideas?

Comment: @jophul post another question with just the MySQL tag and the right people will answer it.